# Resolve class and register return object from one method

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a class `Factory` which has a constructor that takes one parameter and a `Create` method that returns `IClient` object.

```
class Factory
{
  public Factory(SomeParam someParam) 
  { /*...*/ }

  public IClient Create()
  { /*...*/ }
}
```

How can I register that `Factory` in autofac ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first register your factory and then register a delegate which will resolve the factory and return the `IClient.

Of course `SomeParam` should also be registered in *Autofac*

```
builder.RegisterType<ClientFactory>()
       .As<IClientFactory>();
builder.Register(ctx => ctx.Resolve<IClientFactory>().Create())
       .As<IClient>();
```